# Advance Excel Lookup function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

I wanted to use lookup function to lookup for specific value and if the value doesn't exist, it needs to lookup other column.

If the amount is present in Amount1 column it needs to pick it up ..else it needs to pick the amount from amount2 column.

[image]

Output column should have all the values in single column

Answer (score 2):

Try using `BYROW()` with an **implicit intersection** operator `@`

[image]

---

```
=BYROW(F2:F6,LAMBDA(x,@TOROW(FILTER(B2:D6,x=A2:A6,""),1)))
```

---

Or, try as mentioned by **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir, using `MMULT()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `H2`

```
=MMULT(B2:D6*1,{1;1;1})
```

---

Comment: Just for fun: `=MMULT(B2:D6*1,{1;1;1})`.

Comment: @JvdV Sir it works but if the fruits are not aligned as the original then what will i use?

Comment: The question in OP is formulated very poorly, hence I downvoted it. The above comment would simply answer the last part of it *"Output column should have all the values in single column"*.

Comment: @JvdV Sir, understood. I was asking for myself. Not sure about OP, because i agree, the query is very poorly written also they have not shown the output in the screenshot

Comment: Or `=TOCOL(B2:D6,1)`

Answer (score 1):

Use nested `XLOOKUP()`. Try-

```
=XLOOKUP(1,XLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$A$6,$B$2:$D$6),XLOOKUP(G2,$A$2:$A$6,$B$2:$D$6),,1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, perhaps another method to consider:

Use a helper column to get the max value for each row then index with match:

[image]

Then it could be the average of the values or the minimum etc etc

Also note that the order of the input does not need to match the order of the output.

Answer (score 1):

### Sum Up Rows of Filtered Data

In cell `G2`:

**Basic (Copy Down)**

```
=SUM(FILTER($B$2:$D$11,$A$2:$A$11=$F2,""))
```

[image]

**Dynamic (Spills)**

```
=LET(sl,A2:A11,sr,B2:D11,dl,F2:F6,
BYROW(dl,LAMBDA(r,SUM(FILTER(sr,sl=r,"")))))
```

**Excel (Structured) Table**

[image]

In the first cell (row) of the `Amount` column:

```
=SUM(FILTER(Table1[[Amt1]:[Amt3]],Table1[Fruit]=[@Fruit],""))
```

The remaining cells (rows) get populated automatically.